# MySQL join table issue

Tags: mysql

Thinking of the game of golf I want to count the number of times a player has had there handicap cut (handicap_adjustment = -1), but I also want to include the players which haven't been cut at all.

```
PLAYER TABLE ...
PID Name
--- ----
1   Alan
2   Bob
3   Frank
4   Harry
5   Tom

CARD TABLE ...
PID HANDICAP_ADJUSTMENT
--- -------------------
1   -1
1   -1
2   0.2
2   0.2
2   0.2
2   0.2
3   0.2
3   0.2
4   -1
4   -1
4   -1
5   -1

RESULT I WANT IS ....
PID COUNT
--- -----
Alan   2
Bob    0
Frank  0
Harry  3
Tom    1
```

Any ideas of the query?

I can get a count of the pid with handicap_adjustment = -1 in the card table but not sure how to return that to a player query which returns all players with the count in :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name,a.count FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid,COUNT(*) AS count FROM handicap_adjustment GROUP BY pid WHERE handicap_adjustment = -1 ) a ON a.pid = p.pid
```

Comment: I don't think a subquery's necessary here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with a `CASE` expression to get the total. The `CASE` is only including the rows that have a `HANDICAP_ADJUSTMENT = -1`:

```
select p.name,
  count(case when HANDICAP_ADJUSTMENT = -1 then c.pid end) Total
from player p
left join card c
  on p.pid = c.pid
group by p.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/852041/4)

Or you can use `SUM()` with the `CASE` to get the total:

```
select p.name,
  sum(case when HANDICAP_ADJUSTMENT = -1 then 1 else 0 end) Total
from player p
left join card c
  on p.pid = c.pid
group by p.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/852041/5)

Both give the result:

```
|  NAME | TOTAL |
-----------------
|  Alan |     2 |
|   Bob |     0 |
| Frank |     0 |
| Harry |     3 |
|   Tom |     1 |
```

Comment: @user1753622 Happy to help. If this answer or any of the answers to your questions are helpful, then you should consider accepting them via the checkmark on the left of it. It will help future visitors to the site and you will get site rep for accepting. :)